# Passing computed string to x-teleport in alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

I want to append an element to a specific element when the user clicks the button. The scenario goes like this. Is there another way to deal with that kind of problem?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        One
        <button>delete</button>
        <button x-on:click="edit(passIdToFunc)">edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="one" style="display: hidden"></tr>
    <!-- append x-teleport dom node to here when current value is id = one -->

    <tr>Two</tr>
    <tr id="two" style="display: hidden"></tr>

    <tr>Three</tr>
    <tr id="three" style="display: hidden"></tr>

    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- 
  For the initial render, or if there is no table data, 
  I would like to append it to somewhere else with display none.
-->
<template x-teleport="computedString">
  ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the wrong usage for `x-teleport`, though it's not clear from the example where you are teleporting to. You can just use `x-show` to toggle `display:none` if that's what you're looking for.